# Storing large amounts of data locally

Tags: asp.net, memory-management

I'm experienced with ASP.NET but some of my knowledge is a little shaky. I'm creating an application that uses services to get large portions of data. I then want to filter it with LINQ to what I need. This data rarely changes, but I know there's too much of it to fit in Session.

How can I store rarely-changing , large amounts of data in memory? Would this be suitable for Application variables?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you need to do with that data.

Comment: Filter it with LINQ, display it, probably with repeaters, perhaps export it to an XLS file with the data=>XLS functions I already have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of caching the source data, consider using HTTP caching via ASP.NET Output Cache or memcached to store the rendered output itself.  ASP.NET OutputCache can be tuned to work on specific ASP.NET resources and there are many ways to invalidate the cache explicitly if need be.  See the following MSDN resources for more information.

[ASP.NET Caching Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597%28v=vs.100%29)

[Output Cache Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178606%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[OutputCache Attribute for ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can store large amounts of fairly static data:

- In the [HttpContext.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx)
- In a private static field of a C# class.  Wrap the variable with an public get property that can initialize the static field.  The static field will need to be initialized when the app first starts, and any time the app domain is recycled by IIS.

**HttpContext.Cache**

*Pro's*

- Configurable cache expiration policy.
- Designed specifically for the ASP.Net environment

*Con's*

- Might be evoked from cache if ASP.Net determines [it is under-utilized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedreason.aspx).

**Static Field**

*Pro's*

- Complete user control over cache expiration.

*Con's*

- Any cache expiration must be explicitly programmed.  No built-in expiration support.

Comment: A cache is only advantageous if the data is common/shared between clients.  If each client needs it's own version, then the cache is no better than Session state.